# Simple 3D cube in java

Tags: java, 3d, knapsack-problem

How do we code a simple 3d cube in java or multiple 3d cubes made into a container? The cubes will be used as parts of a 3d knapsack problem to build the container and 3 types of parcels. A 3d visual representation for these is needed.

Comment: Can you post what you have done so far on it? Have you looked at alternatives already like lwjgl or Java3D already?

Comment: Do you need hardware acceleration?

Answer (score 1):

Try to learn something like [JOGL](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/) may do the help.